# Spark-Sql Custom Metastore

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive-metastore

In HIVE, we can setup different RDBMs as meta store and let HIVE stores all the metadata in it.
Besides that, by means of hiveserver2, we can make HIVE listens for requests and serves them.

Similarly, there are many documents which say that Spark-SQL can also be used in the similar fashion. Can we setup Oracle (an example) as meta store for Spark-Sql? If yes, can someone please help me how to set it up.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this link: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/demo/demo-connecting-spark-sql-to-hive-metastore.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark uses Hive Metastore as external metastore and you choose your own DB, so Oracle database is fine. Otherwise Spark uses Derby DB which is ok for your own research single user pseudo or small non-production cluster. You need to configure appropriately for external metastore.

In AWS on EMR you can use AWS Glue as external Spark Metastore.

Some of the Distros from vendors imposed some specifics here as well.

Comment: Hi @thebluephantom, thanks for your response! So we can have similar setup for Spark-Sql as we have for HIVE. By using this, we can make Spark-SQL as a DB server (at least DB like). Am I correct ? just to double confirm.

Comment: Not similar but the same. Just u do not use derby but oracle for meta store

Comment: sorry to ask again.. you mean to say, Spark-SQL can only use HIVE setup and can not have a dedicated one for itself ?

Comment: Yes, unless u use Derby which is only single user and not for production purposes. I think u got it.